# Not able to see on contract detail page 'delete' button

Tags: administration, cpq, contracts, steelbrick

[image]

Profile level on contract object having delete permission,and added in pagelayout but still not able see on contarct detail page. i am able to "Renew" and "Amend" buttons
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--> go to profile app permissions

we can find this permission profile level  [image]